# Node module path alias with experimental modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

I use the [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) package to enable path aliases in a node project. E.g. it let's you:

```js
const accountRepo = require('@app/account/account-repo')
```

I'd like to transition the project over to use [experimental modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (enabled with the `--experimental-modules` flag). ES Modules will be enabled without a flag when node 12 goes LTS; thought I'd start experimenting before that. Anyway, module-alias doesn't seem to work with ES modules. I tried adding this to the root of my app (this is the method I was using before transitioning to esm):

```js
require('module-alias/register')
```

I tried changing it to:

```js
import 'module-alias/register'
```

I tried requiring when starting the server:

```sh
node --experimental-modules -r module-alias/register server/app.js
```

None of those methods work. I'm guessing that module-alias overrides the `require` function in order to allow for path aliases, and that of course doesn't work with esm.

I know I can do this with Babel, but I'm using `--experimental-modules` to avoid that.

I also tried a symlink inside the `node_modules` folder, but it didn't seem to work running the app inside a Docker container. Also, it seems hacky/fragile to me.

Does anyone know how to enable path aliases in node with native ES modules?

Answer (score 4):

I posted this as an issue on github. Apparently `module-alias` does not yet support ES modules. However, I got a reply with a potential workaround. I haven't tried it myself, but the poster says it works.

https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/59#issuecomment-500480450

Answer (score 0):

The best solution references [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71370901/module-alias-not-working-with-esm-if-called-from-specific-file) and can be solved by using this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm-module-alias) (that I did).

For instance:

```js
// my-loader.mjs
import generateAliasesResolver from 'esm-module-alias'; 
const aliases = {
  "@root": ".",
  "@deep": "src/some/very/deep/directory/or/file",
  "@my_module": "lib/some-file.js",
  "something": "src/foo"
};
export const resolve = generateAliasesResolver(aliases);
```

And then add `--loader ./my-loader.mjs`, like `node --loader ./my-loader.mjs myscript.js`