# module-alias not working with esm if called from specific file

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, module-alias

I want to use module-alias with esm. I have already found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317999/10140665). The problem is that I am using it manually, like this:

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as moduleAlias from 'module-alias';
moduleAlias.addAlias('@', path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist', 'server'));
```

How can I fix it if it is not directly called by `module-alias/register` but from this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. To do it I just **stop using module-alias** which is at this point an obsolete npm package (+3 year of inactivity as of 19/07/2022) and useful only for the commonjs module resolution.

Citing the right answer from [this github error](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/59#issuecomment-1188375534), the solution is creating a file `custom-loader.mjs` and add it as a loader when calling node

```js
import path from 'node:path';

export default function loadAliases(aliasesToAdd) {
  const getAliases = () => {

    const base = process.cwd();

    const absoluteAliases = Object.keys(aliasesToAdd).reduce((acc, key) =>
      aliasesToAdd[key][0] === '/'
        ? acc
        : { ...acc, [key]: path.join(base, aliasesToAdd[key]) },
      aliasesToAdd)

    return absoluteAliases;

  }

  const isAliasInSpecifier = (path, alias) => {
    return path.indexOf(alias) === 0
      && (path.length === alias.length || path[alias.length] === '/')
  }

  const aliases = getAliases();

  return (specifier, parentModuleURL, defaultResolve) => {

    const alias = Object.keys(aliases).find((key) => isAliasInSpecifier(specifier, key));

    const newSpecifier = alias === undefined
      ? specifier
      : path.join(aliases[alias], specifier.substr(alias.length));

    return defaultResolve(newSpecifier, parentModuleURL);
  }
}

export const resolve = loadAliases({
  "@": "./dist/source",
  "@src": "./dist/source",
  "@test": "./dist/test"
});
```

Then, when calling the script, add `--loader=./custom-loader.mjs`

```bash
node --no-warnings --loader=./custom-loader.mjs myscript.js
```

**UPDATE:** I created [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm-module-alias) to automatically take care of this.

Comment: Thank you for your your npm module. Note that there is a gap in the README of this package. You ask users to run `node --loader=./scripts/alias-loader.mjs`, but there no instructions in README how to create `./scripts/alias-loader.mjs`

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa thanks for the comment, it's a typo and should be `--loader esm-module-alias/loader`, which is an already made loader to make it easier to use the module. For the custom loaders, is written afterwards how to create them